# Evaluate string expression using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to evaluate expressions like below, which are available in string variable, without using eval or external libraries or third party packages:

```
"abs(add(multiply(-1,multiply(-1,subtract(89,19880))),subtract(add(12,add(247,45986)),98)))"
```

Can anyone suggest how it can be done using Javascript or jQuery?

- add(expr1,expr2) - takes two operands and returns their sum.
- subtract(expr1,expr2) - takes two operands and returns their difference (expr1 - expr2).
- multiply(expr1,expr2) - takes two operands and returns their product.
- abs(expr1) - takes one operand and returns its absolute value.

Comment: So you would like extra code? Then don't use `eval()`.

Comment: jQuery is an external library.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the traditional way of expression evaluation using stacks - operand stack, operator stack. Push-pop from the stacks. That's the best way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I did not really bother making the code efficient or bullet proof (there are probably some bugs in here), but here's an example on how you could do it. You could convert your infix expression to a postfix representation as a tokens array and then perform the evaluation of that postfix representation.

NOTE: I did not allow for expressions with spaces to be correctly tokenized, but you could change this if that's not what you need.

```js
var logEl = document.getElementById('log'),
    expInput = document.querySelector('input');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  updateEvaluationResult(expInput.value);
});

updateEvaluationResult(expInput.value);

function updateEvaluationResult(exp) {
  var logMsg;
  try { logMsg = evaluateExpression(exp); }
  catch (e) {
    logMsg = e.message + ('charIndex' in e? ' (char index ' + e.charIndex + ')' : '')
  }
  
  logEl.textContent = logMsg;
  
}


function evaluateExpression(exp) {
  var functions = {
    abs: Math.abs,
    multiply: function(num1, num2) {
      return num1 * num2;
    },
    substract: function(num1, num2) {
      return num1 - num2;
    },
    add: function(num1, num2) {
      return num1 + num2;
    }
  };

  return (evaluateExpression = function(exp) {
    var fn;

    return postfixTokenizationOf(exp).reduce(function(resultStack, token) {
      if (typeof token == 'number') resultStack.push(token);
      else {
        fn = functions[token];
        if (!fn) throw new Error("'" + token + "' is an invalid function");
        resultStack.push(functions[token].apply(
          null, 
          resultStack.splice(resultStack.length - fn.length)
        ));
      }

      return resultStack;
    }, []).pop();
  })(exp);
}

function postfixTokenizationOf(exp) {

  if (!exp) return [];

  var stack = [],
    output = [],
    indexOf = [].indexOf,
    tokenRx = /[^-(),\d]+|[(),]|[-\d]+/g,
    functionTokenRx = /[^-(),\d]+/,
    charTokenHandlers = {
      '(': stack.push.bind(stack, '('),
      ')': handleRightParenthesis,
      ',': handleArgSeperator
    },
    charTokenHandler, token, match;

  while (match = tokenRx.exec(exp)) {
    token = match[0];

    if ((charTokenHandler = charTokenHandlers[token])) {
      charTokenHandler();
      continue;
    }

    if (isNumeric(token)) {
      output.push(+token);
      continue;
    }

    handleFunction();
  }

  if (popStackUntilOneOfTokenFound('()')) throwMismatchedParenthesisError();

  return output;

  function handleFunction() {
    var nextCharIndex = tokenRx.lastIndex;

    if (exp[nextCharIndex] != '(') throwError('expected a function call');
    else stack.push(token);
  }

  function handleRightParenthesis() {
    if (!popStackUntilOneOfTokenFound('(')) throwMismatchedParenthesisError();
    stack.pop();
    if (isFunction(topOfStack())) output.push(stack.pop());
  }

  function handleArgSeperator() {
    if (!popStackUntilOneOfTokenFound('(')) throwError(
      'mismatched parenthesis or misplaced argument seperator'
    );
  }

  function popStackUntilOneOfTokenFound(tokenChars) {
    var t;

    while (indexOf.call(tokenChars, t = topOfStack()) == -1 && t) output.push(stack.pop());

    return !!stack.length;
  }

  function throwError(msg) {
    var err = new Error(msg);
    err.charIndex = tokenRx.lastIndex;
    throw err;
  }

  function throwMismatchedParenthesisError() {
    throwError('mismatched parenthesis');
  }

  function topOfStack() {
    return stack[stack.length - 1];
  }

  function isFunction(token) {
    return functionTokenRx.test(token);
  }

  function isNumeric(token) {
    return parseFloat(token) == token;
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<label>Exp:
  <input type="text" value="abs(add(multiply(-1,multiply(-1,substract(89,19880))),substract(add(12,add(247,45986)),98)))">
</label>

<div id="log"></div>

<button>Evaluate</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is to create a bunch of functions that do what you want, then `eval()` the code.

```
function calc(str){
  function subtract(a, b){
    return a-b;
  }
  function add(a, b){
    return a+b;
  }
  function mulitiply(a, b){
    return a*b;
  }
  function divide(a, b){
    return a/b;
  }
  function abs(a){
    return Math.abs(a);
  }
  return eval('('+str+')');
}
console.log(calc('abs(add(multiply(-1,multiply(-1,subtract(89,19880))),subtract(add(12,add(247,45986)),98)))'));
```

Comment: Why would you not want to use `eval()`? If this is for a school project, tell your teacher to give you practical lessons.

Comment: How can you reach to a result without evaluate something?

Comment: @Litestone How did `eval` got implemented in the first place... and the whole JS language interpreter? There will be an evaluation of the expression, but not using `eval` ;)

Comment: @PHPglue You can ask that to the OP, but there could be many reasons to avoid `eval`.

Comment: I'm laughing on the inside.

Comment: @PHPglue Well... just try `calc('document.write("");')` with your exemple. Using `eval` is very naive in most cases. Not saying that it's never an option, but it's often not an option. Also, `eval` is very limited since the syntax cannot evolve beyond JS syntax. Error reporting could also be an issue...

Answer (score -1):

How about to write your custom functions?

```js
 function add(ad1, ad2) {
     var sum = parseFloat(ad1) + parseFloat(ad2);
     return sum;
 }

 function subtract(sub1, sub2) {
     var sub = parseFloat(sub1) - parseFloat(sub2);
     return sub;
 }

 function multiply(mlt1, mlt2) {
     var mlt = parseFloat(mlt1) * parseFloat(mlt2);
     return mlt;
 }

 function abs(ab1) {
     var abs = Math.abs(parseFloat(ab1));
     return abs;
 }

 function evaluatethis(exp) {
     document.write('<script>alert(' + exp + ');</' + 'script>');
 }
 evaluatethis("abs(add(multiply(-1,multiply(-1,subtract(89,19880))),subtract(add(12,add(247,45986)),98)))");
```